# R ggplot2 geom_smooth line not displayed if overlay text used

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can only get a regression line to display in ggplot or plotly when aes(text) is omitted. Either tooltip text displays or a regression line, but not both. I have been really puzzled as to why since there are no warnings or errors from ggplot/ggplotly.

Dataframe:

```
sum(is.na(cdata2))
[1] 0

str(cdata2)
'data.frame':   2508 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ POPESTIMATE2019: num  55869 223234 24686 22394 57826 ...
 $ ST             : chr  "AL" "AL" "AL" "AL" ...
 $ pdensity       : num  93 140 27 35 89 16 25 187 55 47 ...
 $ STC            : chr  "Alabama-Autauga" "Alabama-Baldwin" "Alabama-Barbour" "Alabama-Bibb" ...
 $ tcases         : int  132 264 92 51 47 58 301 136 329 30 ...
 $ tdeaths        : int  4 8 1 1 1 1 10 3 22 0 ...
 $ SAHdate        : Date, format: "2020-04-04" "2020-04-04" "2020-04-04" "2020-04-04" ...

s <- ggplot(cdata2, aes(x = pdensity,
                        y = tcases,
                        size = tdeaths,
                        color = SAHdate,
                        text=paste0(
                          "<br>St-County: ",STC,
                          "<br>Pop: ",POPESTIMATE2019,
                          "<br>Tot Cases: ",tcases,
                          "<br>People/sq mile: ", pdensity,
                          "<br>Tot Deaths: ", tdeaths))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", na.rm = TRUE, inherit.aes = TRUE);s
```

The result is no regression line.
[image: No regression line with ggplot and text]

If I comment out the text portion:

```
s <- ggplot(cdata2, aes(x = pdensity,
                        y = tcases,
                        size = tdeaths,
                        color = SAHdate)
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", na.rm = TRUE, inherit.aes = TRUE);s
```

The regression line is shown:

[image: ggplot regression line shown]

I tried with plotly using a ton of variations of:

```
fit <- lm(tcases~pdensity, data=cdata2)
ggplotly(s) %>%
 add_trace(x = ~pdensity, y = ~fitted(fit),data = cdata2,mode = 'lines') %>%
 add_lines(x = ~pdensity, y = ~fitted(fit),data = cdata2,mode = 'lines')

`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
Error in min(x, na.rm = na.rm) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

I am stumped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't answer exactly ***why*** you get this behavior, but you are correct and... it is odd.  I did some detective work with a simple example case: `df <- data.frame(x=1:1000, y=rexp(1000))`.  I adjusted the global `aes()` terms a bunch, looking for when the line disappeared.  Results are below:

```
g <- list(geom_point(), geom_smooth())

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + g  # control
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, text=x)) + g  # OK
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, text='x')) + g   # OK
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, text=paste(x))) + g  # NO LINE SHOWN
```

The workaround for this is already kind of in your code, which is to set `inherit.aes=FALSE` in `geom_smooth()`.  For whatever reason, it doesn't like `paste()` being used in the `text=` aesthetic.  This means you have to restate your `x` and `y` aesthetics in `geom_smooth`, but it works fine:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, text=paste(x))) +
    geom_point() + geom_smooth(inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(x,y))
```

[image]

Comment: I was replying "thanks but I already had 10 various iterations with inherit.aes = FALSE" however I ran the code again and simply using aes(y,x) solved the issue. I must have had everything but aes(y,x). I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I tried moving "text=..." inside `geom_point()`, like this:

```
p = p + geom_point(aes(text = paste("ID ",sampleID))
```

Although it will give a warning message, when I generate *plotly* with:

```
ggplotly(p)
```

it works out.